# python script: git checkout prior to running

Tags: python, git, github, integration

I've started to use gitHub to manage the development process of production scripts running daily on my workstation (via cron).

One way to make sure that the lastest valid production version runs would be to run a `git checkout` inside the production directory, moments prior to running the target script. I was wondering if it can be done from within the production script (i.e. checking is this is the latest version, if not, `git checkout`, if yes, do nothing and run)

Answer (score 1):

It *is* certainly *possible* to do this, e.g. (untested):

```
git fetch &&
ahead=$(git rev-list --count master..origin/master) &&
case "$ahead" in
0)  ;; # run normally
*)  echo "I seem to be out of date"
    git merge --ff-only || { echo "update failed, quitting"; exit 1; }
    exec <path-to-script>;;
esac
# ... normal part of script here
```

But this is also almost certainly the wrong approach.  Instead of doing that, schedule a job—a script—that consists of:

```
git fetch && git merge --ff-only && exec <path-to-script>
```

This script can live in the same repository.  It's a separate script whose job is to update in place—which, if there's nothing to do, is a no-op (it says "Already up to date." and then exits 0 = success)—and then run the other script, whether it's updated or not.  This provides a clean separation of purpose: one script updates; one script runs; there's no weird mix of self-update-and-oops-now-I-have-to-quit-because-maybe-my-code-is-different.

Note that adding `--quiet` to the `git merge --ff-only` suppresses the "Already up to date." message, which may be helpful if your version of cron emails you the output when there is output.  (If your version of cron *doesn't* do this, it probably should be upgraded to one that does.)  So you probably really want:

```
git fetch && git merge --ff-only --quiet && exec <path-to-script>
```

The fetch followed by merge is what `git pull` does by default, but `git pull` is a program meant to be run by a human.  Git divides its various programs into so-called *porcelain* and *plumbing*, and the porcelain commands are the ones meant for humans, while the plumbing ones are meant for writing scripts.  Git's division here is quite imperfect: some commands are both plumbing *and* porcelain, and there are some varieties that are missing (e.g., `git log` is porcelain, but there are no plumbing commands for some of what it does)—but to the extent that you can, it's usually wise to stick to this pattern.

Comment: will try your second option, cleaner. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case it might be useful, here's the python script I am using now. I call it from vim immediately after a `commit`.

```
#!/bin/python3
"""
This script syncs development -> production branches
Both directories are connected to the same repository
Assume projectP (for production) and projectD (for development)
"""
####################################################
# Modules
####################################################
import git
####################################################
# Globals
####################################################
theProjectD = "path_to_projectD"
theProjectP = "path_to_projectP"
####################################################
# Code
####################################################
# push & merge develop to main from the develop directory
repo = git.Repo(theProjectD)
repo.remotes.origin.push()
repo.git.checkout('main')
repo.git.merge('develop')
repo.remotes.origin.push()
repo.git.checkout('develop')

# fetch latest version of main in the production directory
repo = git.Repo(theProjectP)
repo.remotes.origin.fetch()
repo.remotes.origin.pull()
```